# UWP: WinJS webview preventDefault not working after Windows update 1703

Tags: dom, uwp, win-universal-app, winjs, dom-events

Windows 10 Creators Update 1703 brought a new issue to my UWP app - I use a WinJS webview to open a web page which navigates to "myscheme://blahblah" after some time. I usually listen to MSWebViewUnsupportedUriSchemeIdentified to catch this event, call event.preventDefault(), and parse the "blahblah" part for my usage.

Before update 1703, the web page was displaying properly, but now that I have updated my windows 10 machine, the webview is blank once the page navigates to myscheme://blahblah. Almost as if event.preventDefault() doesnt work anymore. Anyone know how I can find out if any changes in 1703 cause this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Using window.external.notify() and listening to MSWebViewScriptNotify events is 100x better for passing data than listening for unsupported URI schemes, and it fixed my issue.